# Installing CodeIgniter On Amazon EC2

Tags: windows, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

This is the first time I'm trying to upload my completed CodeIgniter project to a micro instance of Amazon EC2. Here is what I did so far: I created 1 micro instance on Amazon EC2 using "Amazon Linux AMI", installed software (gcc, make, httpd, php-common php-cli php-pear, php-devel, git) using YUM via Putty, and uploaded my completed CodeIgniter project to my "ec2-user" folder using FileZilla.

My question is, how do I configure EC2 and my project in order to view my project's home page using my public DNS address given to me by Amazon? (Visiting my public DNS address displays the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and change `DocumentRoot` to the directory where your files are.

Also, in the future, you will have better luck with these types of questions on  https://serverfault.com/

Comment: +1 Thank you very much stormdrain. I actually tried to transfer my CodeIgniter website to /var/www/html using FileZilla but I got hundreds of transfer errors (permission denied errors) as it was attempting to upload my website.

Comment: np. There were probably permission issues with the /var/www/html folder and the (s)ftp user. Check out http://www.linux.org/article/view/file-permissions-chmod